# Doctrine 2: is multiple level STI possible?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to have multiple level single table inheritance, is this possible?  For example, if I have a billable_items table that I would like to split into client and consultants, and add a second level to the consultants, like 'wage', 'referral', 'transportation', etc, would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: as the documentation states, you just need to define the entire inheritance hierarchy in the discriminator map of the TOPMOST class.  For any 2nd level base/abstract parent classes, you would NOT include them in the discriminator map, just make sure you add the entity annotation.